# Using timestamp column value in TIMEDIFF function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to measure the difference between two timestamps, i.e. now and a stored date from previous. How would I go about selecting from a table and using the result (timestamp) as a parameter for TIMEDIFF?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. Can you give an exmaple of the data you have and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a column which stores a timestamp value - it just stores the current date when a row is inserted. And I want to then calculate the time difference between now and the value which is stored. 'now' being after that row is inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `now()` to retreive the current date and the name of the column to get its value:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF (NOW(), my_col)
FROM   my_table
```